# What is the best way to inspect a specific variable in jupyter?

Tags: jupyter

Short of printing a variable in a new cell, I don't know a good fast method to view a specific variable in jupyter.

I am aware of the Variable Inspector nbextension; but that shows ALL variables rather than a specific one.

Is there some way to do this which I'm missing?

Comment: Were you hoping for some sort of hover-over popup?  Or other inspection window?  Admittedly I use notebooks much like I use a `ipython` terminal session, where simply typing the variable in a new line is the natural way of view it (or for a big array I may ask for shape, dtype or other property).  Displaying the variable in the new cell seems natural enough.

Comment: yes; hover over, exactly. this is a. costly on time and b. leaves you with a bunch of cells showing variables unless you habitually delete it. this is not the solution I'm looking for